# Converting Negative numbers with TADOQuery

Tags: oracle, delphi, casting, activex, bcd

I have a huge problem with `TADOQuery`:

This is my SQL:

```
select cast(-10 as number(9)) foo, -10 bar 
  from dual
```

Instead of TBCDField, a TIntegerField will be created when you add the "foo" field, because the type is changed at this point:

```
procedure TCustomADODataSet.InternalInitFieldDefs;

    if (F.Type_ = adNumeric) and (F.NumericScale = 0) and
       (F.Precision < 10) then
      FieldType := ftInteger;
```

the function:

```
function TCustomADODataSet.GetFieldData(Field: TField; Buffer: Pointer;
  NativeFormat: Boolean): Boolean;
```

Is not considering the signal at this point:

```
    ftAutoInc, ftInteger:
      Integer(Buffer^) := lVal;
```

the value of `tagVariant` for TIntegerField is:

(14, 32768, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 1.4012984643e-44, 4.9406564584e-323, True, 10, 0.001, 4.9406564584e-323, , $A, $A, $A, $A, $A, $A, $A, $A, $A, $A, $A, $A, $A '', $A, $A, $A, $A, $A, #10, 10, 10, 10, 10, $A, , $A, $A, $A, $A)

which is the same for TBCDField:

(14, 32768, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 1.4012984643e-44, 4.9406564584e-323, True, 10, 0.001, 4.9406564584e-323, , $A, $A, $A, $A, $A, $A, $A, $A, $A, $A, $A, $A, $A '', $A, $A, $A, $A, $A, #10, 10, 10, 10, 10, $A, , $A, $A, $A, $A)

The foo value will be 10 and the bar value will be -10.

Is this a bug? 
There is a WorkAround? 
It was fixed?

I'd tested using Microsoft OLEDB provider for Oracle and Oracle Provider for OLEDB.
All tests have been done using Delphi 6.

Comment: any suggestions? doubts?

Comment: I haven't got any Oracle db about to try this this with.  ;-)

Comment: If there is a bug its at the ADO recordset level. :-)

Comment: Try using precision of 10. i.e. `select cast(-10 as number(10)) foo`. Can you do that? other option would be to replace ADODB.pas (or override) `TCustomADODataSet.GetFieldData`. [see here](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/75/218433.html)

Comment: @kobik the select is assembled by user, i can't previse this situation.

Comment: @MatheusFreitas, I see. then look at the link provided to fix ADODB.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i have understood correctly, however try in this way:

```
select cast(replace(-10,'-','') as number(9)) foo, -10 bar 
  from dual;
```